# Conventions regarding the return type for add() methods

Tags: java, conventions

What is the Java programming convention for `add(...)` methods? Example:

- `TreeSet`: `public void add(...)`
- `BigInteger`: `public BigInteger add(...)`

Why is it that for `TreeSet` the return type is void, while for `BigInteger` the return type is `BigInteger`?

When should I use void in my own methods?

Comment: `BigInteger.add` maps directly to a mathematical operation, so of course it is going to return something. And `TreeSet.add` does return a value - it returns a `boolean` indicating if the element already existed in the set.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072519/java-add-method-convention

Answer (score 2):

If your `add` operation is immutable, it should return some value (this is the case of `BigInteger`). Else you should return `void` (the case of `Collection`, for example, `TreeSet`).

Answer (score 1):

It is a design choice. It is mostly centered around the question whether you want your objects (instances) to be mutable or immutable.

A collection, including `TreeSet` is mutable, because obviously you want to add elements to it. By adding objects to itself, you 'change' the instance, the values it contains. It does not have to return anything. However, some developers like to be able to chain multiple operations, so if you wanted something like:

```
TreeSet set = new TreeSet();
set.add(oneElement).add(anotherElement);
```

Then yes, instead of having void as the return type, you might have choosen another TreeSet (itself) as the return type. The choice was made for us: it is void.

A `BigInteger` was chosen by design to be immutable (contained values cannot change). So instead of changing its own value, it needs to return a new instance, much like itself, but with the new value. There are no 'setXxxx()' methods available on `BigInteger` that allows you to the value of an existing `BigInteger` instance.

[Update]

Ok - you almost had me there. `TreeSet::add` does not have `void` but `boolean` as the return type. So that was another design choice made ... not only is a TreeSet a mutable object, they also want something useful after trying to add an element: whether the `add` was successful. This is because a `Set`, including a `TreeSet` only adds, and contains, distinct elements. If the element is already there, it wont be added again, and the `add` method will return you a `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Basically when it makes sense. If you're adding an item to a set or another type of adding that doesn't actually return anything, but simply works on an object, use `void`. If you're adding a number to another number, like BigInteger's add function does, you can return the sum.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends; typically you return an instance of the object itself if it "makes sense" to do so. In your particular example, you're seeing the difference between an immutable object and a mutable one. `TreeSet` instances are mutable, and when you call `add` on an instance, that very same instance is modified. `BigInteger` instances are immutable, and so when you add to it, you get a new instance with the sum of the two values; the original instance remains unchanged.

In some cases the method may return an instance of itself because it can be used to provide a fluent interface.